# Add initiated array objects from Another class file thats occurring in Main into stack

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, object, stack

I am trying to get the initiated objects in Main (The initiation is occurring in the main but is pulling from a class in the Christmas class file: the courtney.addGift("Dog"); .. etc) into myHoliday Stack.

**How would I get the initiated object in main courtney.addGift("Dog") -- the addGift is pulling from the Christmas class file -- into myHoliday stack?**

This is the Christmas file:

**Christmas**

```
    public class Christmas {

    ArrayList<String> gifts;
    // add a constructor that takes no arguments and initializes
    // the previous properties

    public Christmas()
    {

        gifts = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    // add a method called addGift that accepts a string
    // and adds it to the gifts data structure
    public void addGift(String gift) 
    {
        gifts.add(gift);
    }

}
```

**Main**

```
 public static void DemoChristmas()
    {
    // create a couple of Christmas objects and add them to a stack
    //Pop them off the stack and print them as you go 

        Christmas courtney = new Christmas();
        Christmas alexandra = new Christmas();
        Christmas bobby = new Christmas();
        Christmas jackie = new Christmas();

        Stack<Christmas> myHoliday = new Stack<Christmas>();

        // initiate the Christmas objects 
        courtney.addGift("Dog");
        alexandra.addGift("Hat");
        jackie.addGift("Car");
        bobby.addGift("Socks");
        // add them to the stack

    }
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question or indicated what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1. In your Christmas class make the suitable `getters` and `setters`
2. If you want to print the content of `stack` you need to Override the `toString()` of your Christmas class.

```java
class Christmas {
    private ArrayList<String> gifts;

    public Christmas() {
        gifts = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public void addGift(String gift) {
        gifts.add(gift);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getGifts() {
        return gifts;
    }

    public void setGifts(ArrayList<String> gifts) {
        this.gifts = gifts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder giftName = new StringBuilder();
        for (String gift : gifts){
            giftName.append(gift);
            giftName.append(" ");
        }
        return giftName.toString().trim();
    }
}
```

Also, this is not the correct way to print a stack.

```java
private static void printStack(Stack<Christmas> stack) {
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) System.out.println(stack.pop());
}
```

could be one way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to properly initialize your Christmas-type elements,

```
myHoliday.push(courtney)
```

will, for example, add your courtney object to the top of the stack.

Comment: When I do that and try to print myHoliday it doesn't seem to print.

Comment: System.out.println("The Stack is: " + myHoliday);

Comment: @CourtneyJoYoung You can't print Stacks with a simple println.  Doing that uses the stack's `toString` method, which just prints out the classname and hashcode.  You'll have to write some extra code to loop through the elements of the stack (maybe by using `myHoliday.toArray()` to get an array representation of the data), and manually print the contents of the objects in the array.